# Calculate values of textboxes automatically

Tags: javascript

can you help to automatically compute the grand total of the prices?
http://chocolatehillsadventurepark.com/reservation.php

my code will go like these:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$('#num_chicken'), $('#num_chicken').on('keyup',function(){
    var tot = $('#price_chicken').val() * this.value;
    $('#total_chicken').val(tot);
});

$('#num_fish'), $('#num_fish').on('keyup',function(){
    var tot = $('#price_fish').val() * this.value;
    $('#total_fish').val(tot);
});

</script>
```

and so on.....

Hope for your immediate response.
Thank you!

Comment: What do you think `$('#num_chicken'), $('#num_chicken').on(...)` does?

Comment: yeah!..sorry...just a mistake..$('#num_chicken').on('keyup',function(){
      var tot = $('#price_chicken').val() * this.value;
      $('#total_chicken').val(tot);
     });
     
     $('#num_fish').on('keyup',function(){
      var tot = $('#price_fish').val() * this.value;
      $('#total_fish').val(tot);
     });

Comment: Can you please help me Mr. T.J. Crowder?..

Answer (score 0):

you need to put those in `$( document ).ready(function() {});` like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#num_chicken').on('keyup', function () {
        var tot = $('#price_chicken').val() * this.value;
        $('#total_chicken').val(tot);
    });
    $('#num_fish').on('keyup', function () {
        var tot = $('#price_fish').val() * this.value;
        $('#total_fish').val(tot);
    });

});
```

**upDate: calculate grand total**
you can use the following code to calculate the grand total

```
function calculateGrandTotal() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $('table tbody tr td:nth-child(4) input').each(function (index) {
        grandTotal += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('#grand_total').val(grandTotal);
}
```

you need to call this at the end of each `.on('keyup', function () {` like

```
$('#num_chicken').on('keyup', function () {
    var tot = $('#price_chicken').val() * this.value;
    $('#total_chicken').val(tot);
    calculateGrandTotal();   // add this
});
$('#num_fish').on('keyup', function () {
    var tot = $('#price_fish').val() * this.value;
    $('#total_fish').val(tot);
    calculateGrandTotal();   // add this
});
```

Comment: thank you so much!...but how would i call or how would i compute the grand total?...because i need to add the total of each activity to have the grand total...e.g $('#total_chicken') + $('#total_fish') ........

Comment: @ juan dela cruz is there some event for example on some element click you want to calculate grand total??

Comment: what do you mean by updated one?...im sorry,.im just new in JS

Comment: what does 4 mean in this line $('table tbody tr td:nth-child(4) input').each(function (index) {

Comment: these are the total for `Activitys`

Comment: make sure `Activity` total should not be blank

Comment: @ juan dela cruz now you can `mark` it as `answer` and `vote it up` as well